# Prove $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}dx=\infty$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, elementary-functions

How do I prove the following?
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}dx=\infty $$

Comment: It depends highly on what tools you want to allow yourself. If you take for granted that $\ln x$ tends to minus infinity at $0$ then you're done.

Comment: Oh yes, that solves this question.

Comment: Does it make any difference whether we take primitive function or the Riemannian approach?

Comment: The result is the same of course, I was saying that because sometimes people have requirements as to what methods are allowed (what they have seen so far, what was in the earlier chapters of their book...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative approach: assume that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x}=C\in\mathbb{R}^+$. By enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto 2z$ we have

$$ C=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x} = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{dz}{z} $$
from which it follows that
$$ 0 = \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{dy}{y} \geq \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{dy}{1} = \frac{1}{2}, $$
contradiction.

Comment: Oh yes, nice, but how have you defrived these two relations $$ 0 = \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{dy}{y} \geq \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{dy}{1}$$?

Comment: @user122424 the first equality holds by additivity of the integral, and the second because $1/y$ is greater than $1$ when $0<y<1$.

Comment: How do you precisely use additivity of the integral to get $$ 0 = \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\frac{dy}{y}$$

Comment: $$\int_{1/2}^{1} = \int_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1/2}$$

Comment: I didn't realize that my innocent question might have such a beautiful answer as this one.

Comment: @user122424: actually the same principle is well-known to allow a simple proof of $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n}=+\infty$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Why there is no Jacobian (in our case the number $(2z)'=2$) involved in the r.h.s. term here: 
$$ C=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x} = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{dz}{z}? $$

Comment: @user122424: $\frac{dx}{x}$ is invariant under $x\mapsto Cz$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Could you please write down the whole formula explaining why the Jacobian is equal to $1$ on the r.h.s.? Perhaps I do not follow what invariance means here.

Comment: @user122424: $$ \int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{x}\stackrel{x\mapsto 2z}{=}\int_{a/2}^{b/2}\frac{2\,dz}{2z}=\int_{a/2}^{b/2}\frac{dz}{z}=\int_{a/2}^{b/2}\frac{dx}{x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}dx=\left[\ln|x|\right]_0^1=\lim_{x\to 0}\ln(x)=\infty$$

Comment: Almost.${}{}{}$

Comment: Dubious that the area under a positive function could be an extremely large negative number ...

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^1\frac1x\operatorname{dx}=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^1\frac1x\operatorname{dx}=\lim_{\epsilon \to0^+}[\ln x]_{\epsilon}^1=\ln1-\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+} \ln\epsilon=0-(-\infty)=\infty $.